# Barracuda Archiver syncing folders in a resource domain exchange topology?

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2013, barracuda

I have an Exchange 2013 deployment in a resource domain.
The user accounts exist in several trusted domains.

For the most of the archiver functionality this works fine.
I have found an issue with syncing users mailbox folder structures.

I have LDAP connections to both the resource domain dc's and the user account domain dc's.
Due to the fact that there are two connections to two different domains when you search for a specific account the drop down / autocomplete displays two email addresses for each specific account.
When using "Search as User" only one of the two accounts  listed has a folder structure.

The problem seems to lie in the fact that it syncs the folders for the user account in the resource domain. When the user logs in, they use the user account domain and no folders are displayed.

If I remove the ldap connection to the user account domain, when I search for a user it displays only one user and that account has a folder structure but in this configuration the user can't log in.

When the connection to the user account domain is there, the user can log in but there is no folder structure.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That's actually a known bug with the Barracuda Message Archiver. If you call or email Barracuda support, they can help get it patched up on your box so Folder Sync will work with shared resource deployments of Exchange.

Comment: Thanks! I've been working with Barracuda support since I asked this question and feel like I'm banging my head against a wall.